# ruby loop through two arrays and group them based on a condition

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays and would like to loop through both and based on a condition put them into groups.  I have done this and it does not give me what I need.

```
len = [24,71,312,99,89]
diff = [11,7,7,21,3]

a = []

len.zip(diff).each do |l,d|
    if d < 10
        a << l
    else
        a << [l]
    end
end
```

I like to have the results look like this:

```
a = [[24], [71,312], [99,89]]
```

I like to then add up each group within the array, so to have:

```
a = [24, 383, 188]
```

Would appreciate some assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Explain how you want to put them in groups.

Comment: your specification does not match your desired output.  `len.zip(diff)` produces and array of tuples that includes `[99, 21], [89, 3]`.  No matter if we take you meaning of `d < 10` was inverted, it does not seem that `[99,89]` can be produced

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is [`chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
len.zip(diff).chunk { |l, d| d < 10 }.map { |_, d| d.map(&:first).inject(:+) }
# => [24, 383, 99, 89]
```

(I assume that the grouping is by having diff smaller or bigger than 10, which means the correct grouping is `[[24], [71,312], [99], [89]]`, and not as is written in the OP)

Comment: That does not match the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  If you want to keep the basic approach you've taken, you could modify your code as follows:

**Code**

```
def doit(len, diff)
  a = []
  b = []
  len.zip(diff).each do |l,d|
    if d < 10
      b << l
    else
      (a << b; b = []) if b.any?
      a << [l]
    end
  end
  a << b if b.any?
  a.map { |e| e.reduce(:+) }
end
```

**Example**

```
len  = [24, 71, 312, 99, 89]
diff = [11,  7,   7, 21, 13]

doit(len, diff) #=> [24, 383, 99, 89]
```

Like everyone else, I assume your desired result should be as I've shown.

**Explanation**

```
a = []
b = []
last = nil

arr = len.zip(diff)
  #=> [[24, 11], [71, 7], [312, 7], [99, 21], [89, 3]]

enum = arr.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[24, 11], [71, 7], [312, 7], [99, 21], [89, 3]]:each>
```

We can convert the enumerator `enum` to an array so see the values it will pass into its block:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[24, 11], [71, 7], [312, 7], [99, 21], [89, 3]]
```

The first value `enum` passes to the block assigns the following values to its block variable:

```
l => 24
d => 11
```

Since `d < 10` is `false`, `b.any? #=> false` means we do not execute `a << b; b = []`, but we do execute:

```
a << l #=> [24]
```

`enum` now passes the second element to the block and sets the block variables to:

```
l => 71
d =>  7
```

As `d < 10` is now `true`, we execute:

```
b << l #=> [71]
```

and `a` remains unchanged.  Next,

```
l => 312
d =>  7
```

so

```
b << l #=> [71, 312]
```

Next:

```
l => 99
d => 21
```

Since `b.any? => true`:

```
a << b   #=> [[24], [71, 312]]
b = []   #=>  []
a << [l] #=> [[24], [71, 312], [312]]
```

After `enum` has passed all its elements to the block,

```
a #=> [[24], [71, 312], [99]]
b #=>  [89]
```

so

```
a << b if b.any?
  #=> [[24], [71, 312], [99], [89]]
```

is executed. If the last value of `diff` had been, say, 13, rather than 3, `b #=> []`, so `a << b` would not be executed.

Lastly,

```
a.map { |e| e.reduce(:+) }
  #=> [24, 383, 99, 89]
```